# Using list comprehension to setup a list of unique dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, nested-lists

I have the following dictionary

```
stocklist = {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}
```

And I want to setup a grid of HEIGHT by WIDTH where each cell in the grid has it's own unique version of a stocklist with different values. Will this work?

```
stockmap = [[stocklist for w in range(WIDTH)] for h in range(HEIGHT)]
```

I have other lists of width by height where each cell contains only one value, and they work fine.

But previous to this I tried to solve my issue by using Classes and it was a nightmare as my instances contained a list that kept being identical.

I'm worried that if I start coding the above I'll end up with the same problem.

Comment: use `stockmap = [[dict(stocklist) for w in range(WIDTH)] for h in range(HEIGHT)]`

Comment: With `stocklist = {a: 0, b: 0, c: 0}` I get an error. I'm using 2.7 `"TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed"`

Comment: @PierreLafortune I have edited the original code, in which the dictionary keys lacked single brackets around them :)

Comment: A follow up to my question above; what would be the correct syntax to then access a specific grids deep.copy of the list? For example below I want to add one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example each 'cell' of your grid will point to the same dictionary - `stocklist`. So if you modify one 'cell' actually all of them will change.

If you need to store different dict in each cell you should create deep copies of the stocklist.

try:

```
import copy
stocklist = {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}
stockmap = [[copy.deepcopy(stocklist) for w in range(WIDTH)] for h in range(HEIGHT)]
```

---

In the simple example, where your `stocklist` does not contain any nested dict also

```
`stockmap = [[dict(stocklist) for w in range(WIDTH)] for h in range(HEIGHT)]`
```

will work. However remember that if your `stocklist` would be something like `{'a': 0, 'b': {'c': 0}}`, the internal - nested dict `{'c': 0}` will not be deep copied and each 'cell' will share that dict.

Answer (score 1):

As I suggested above, you need to instantiate a new object, for example using `dict`

```
stockmap = [[dict(stocklist) for w in range(WIDTH)] for h in range(HEIGHT)]
```

otherwise the very same dictionary instance would be used.

Let's check it out:

with your example

```
>>> HEIGHT = 3
>>> WIDTH = 3
>>> stocklist = {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}
>>> stockmap = [[stocklist for w in range(WIDTH)] for h in range(HEIGHT)]
>>> stockmap
[[{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}], [{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}], [{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}]]
>>> stocklist['a']=9
>>> stockmap
[[{'a': 9, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, {'a': 9, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, {'a': 9, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}], [{'a': 9, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, {'a': 9, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, {'a': 9, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}], [{'a': 9, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, {'a': 9, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, {'a': 9, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}]]
```

as you can clearly see, modifying one item in the original dictionary affects the newly created list (grid)

Whereas doing

```
>>> stockmap = [[dict(stocklist) for w in range(WIDTH)] for h in range(HEIGHT)]
>>> stockmap
[[{'a': 9, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, {'a': 9, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, {'a': 9, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}], [{'a': 9, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, {'a': 9, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, {'a': 9, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}], [{'a': 9, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, {'a': 9, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, {'a': 9, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}]]
>>> stocklist['a']=5
>>> stockmap
[[{'a': 9, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, {'a': 9, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, {'a': 9, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}], [{'a': 9, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, {'a': 9, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, {'a': 9, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}], [{'a': 9, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, {'a': 9, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, {'a': 9, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}]]
```

leaves the grid unaltered

Note: as @damgad correctly points out, `dict` would not work for nested dictionaries. In such cases you need to use `copy.deepcopy`